# Disable Screen Time notifications

Tags: ios, screen-time

Is it possible to disable notifications for [Screen Time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208982) while leaving notifications in general enabled?

There's no toggle to disable notifications under it's settings (at least on iOS 12.1.2) and Screen Time doesn't appear under the apps section as a separate app either.

The use case is that I only enable important notifications and I don't want to get this notification on Sunday mornings, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my iOS version (12.1.4) there is an option to disable Screen Time notifications in the standard Notification Settings.

Make sure:

- You're on the latest iOS version, to update go to *Settings* -> *Software Update*.
- Screen time is turned on
- You're accessing the notifications in the right place (*Settings* -> *Notifications*)